# ambigious column name in sql server

Tags: sql

hello i'm having a ambiguous column name in m stored procedure for payment .bid-id can someone help to resolve this issue please?

```
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
  (
  ORDER BY [PaymentID] ASC
  )AS RowNumber
  ,[PaymentID]
  ,[Name]
  ,[WinningPrice]
  ,[PaymentDate]
   ,[Payment.BidID]
 INTO #Results
 FROM  Item INNER JOIN
                         Auction ON Item.ItemID = Auction.ItemID INNER JOIN
                         BID ON Auction.AuctionID = BID.AuctionID INNER JOIN
                         Payment ON BID.BidID = Payment.BidID
                         Where   (BID.Status = 'Paid') AND (BID.BuyerID = @buyer)

  SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM #Results

  SELECT * FROM #Results
  WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

  DROP TABLE #Results
End
```

Comment: Have tried TableName.ColumnName in your select?

Comment: Don't you also get an error on `[Payment.BidID]`?

Comment: yes @IdanArye i get the error there

Comment: @Mathias yes i tried this too

Comment: Have you tried [Payment].[BidID] or using aliases as most would suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good practice is using aliases like:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (
        ORDER BY i.[PaymentID] ASC  --which table it belongs? put correct alias
    )AS RowNumber
    ,i.[PaymentID]                  
    ,i.[Name]
    ,i.[WinningPrice]
    ,i.[PaymentDate]
    ,p.[BidID]
INTO #Results
FROM  Item i
INNER JOIN Auction a 
    ON i.ItemID = a.ItemID 
INNER JOIN  BID b
    ON a.AuctionID = b.AuctionID 
INNER JOIN Payment p 
    ON b.BidID = p.BidID
Where   (b.Status = 'Paid') 
        AND (b.BuyerID = @buyer)

SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
FROM #Results
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a column name you use in the query that is available in multiple tables.

Without the table structure we can't be certain which one it is, but probably one with an alias in your query:

```
,[PaymentID]
,[Name]
,[WinningPrice]
,[PaymentDate]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Create a alias for ambiguous column name

```
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
  (
  ORDER BY [PaymentID] ASC
  )AS RowNumber
  ,[PaymentID]
  ,[Name]
  ,[WinningPrice]
  ,[PaymentDate]
   ,[Payment.BidID] as PBidID
 INTO #Results
 FROM  Item INNER JOIN
                         Auction ON Item.ItemID = Auction.ItemID INNER JOIN
                         BID ON Auction.AuctionID = BID.AuctionID INNER JOIN
                         Payment ON BID.BidID = Payment.BidID
                         Where   (BID.Status = 'Paid') AND (BID.BuyerID = @buyer)

  SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM #Results

  SELECT * FROM #Results
  WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

  DROP TABLE #Results
End
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
  (
  ORDER BY [PaymentID] ASC
  )AS RowNumber
  ,[PaymentID]
  ,[Name]
  ,[WinningPrice]
  ,[PaymentDate]
   ,[Payment.BidID]
 INTO #Results
 FROM  Item INNER JOIN
                         Auction ON Item.ItemID = Auction.ItemID INNER JOIN
                         BID ON Auction.AuctionID = BID.AuctionID INNER JOIN
                         **Payment P1 ON BID.BidID = P1.BidID**
                         Where   (BID.Status = 'Paid') AND (BID.BuyerID = @buyer)

  SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM #Results

  SELECT * FROM #Results
  WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

  DROP TABLE #Results
End
```

Hope this helps..

highlighted the line which i changed